# benefit of updating sql server with latest service pack

Tags: sql-server

What are the benefit of updating sql server with latest service pack ? What are the threats of not updating sql server with latest service pack ? what can be the effect on business for the same ?

Comment: You can check update package description on its downloading site what all added/fixed features. Like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2931693 . Benefit: You get fixed updates, threat: You don't get fixed updates.

Comment: that's a very vague question that cannot have a final answer. a service pack maybe needed or not, provide no improvement at all and be a disruptive upgrade you are willing to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

As a rule of thumb: "If it ain't broken, don't fix it".

Are you experiencing any problems with your current installation? If so, take a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803383.aspx) to see if your issues have been fixed in any of the Service Packs.

Generally speaking, it should be quite safe to install a Service Pack. Furthermore, some Service Packs contain fixes that improve the performance and stability of SQL Server. But again, if you are not experiencing any issues at all, there's really no need to jeopardize a production environment with the installation of new software.